# Autocomplete Jquery remote data not auto filter like local array

Tags: jquery, filter, autocomplete, asp-classic

I am starting with simple autocomplete from Jquery in two cases: local array and remote source data from other page. I am sure the data for both be the same but Autocomplete work differently. Refer my code below:

***1. With local array***

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtArr").autocomplete({
        source: programmingLang,
        change:function(event, ui){
            if (ui.item==null)
                $('#txtArr').val(-1);
        }
        })
})
```

**programmingLang array:**

```
var programmingLang = [{ "value": "ActionScript", "id": 31 }, { "value": "AppleScript", "id": 2 }, { "value": "JavaScript", "id": 3 }, { "value": "Haskell", "id": 33 }, { "value": "Architects", "id": 27 }, { "value": "Scheme", "id": 1 }, { "value": "PHP", "id": 29 }, { "value": "Marketing", "id": 25 }, { "value": "Perl", "id": 15 }, { "value": "Training", "id": 32}];
```

From browser, I typed p, ..., items which contain 'p' dispayed in list - perfect:)

***2. Remote by source data***

**Javascript code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtArr").autocomplete({
        source: "script.asp",
        change:function(event, ui){
            if (ui.item==null)
                $('#txtArr').val(-1);
        }
        })
})
```

**script.asp**

```
<%    
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"    
Response.Write("[{ ""value"": ""ActionScript"", ""id"": 31 }, { ""value"": ""AppleScript"", ""id"": 2 }, { ""value"": ""JavaScript"", ""id"": 3 }, { ""value"": ""Haskell"", ""id"": 33 }, { ""value"": ""Architects"", ""id"": 27 }, { ""value"": ""Scheme"", ""id"": 1 }, { ""value"": ""PHP"", ""id"": 29 }, { ""value"": ""Marketing"", ""id"": 25 }, { ""value"": ""Perl"", ""id"": 15 }, { ""value"": ""Training"", ""id"": 32}]")
%>
```

From browser: type p ... all items in array be listed :(

How can I fix for both of them work the same as local array?

Many thanks.

---

It works now. I modify the **script.asp** similar as advice of **elliottjmills**

```
 <%    
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
strSql="SELECT * FROM HR_Employee WHERE **Fullname like '%" & request.QueryString("term")** & "%'"   

strconn="PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=...;DATABASE=...;USER ID=...;PASSWORD=...;"  

set conTem=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conTem.Open(strconn)

Set rsElementTem = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsElementTem.Open strSql,conTem,3,3
strArr=""
if not rsElementTem.EOF then
    rsElementTem.MoveFirst
    'rsElementTem.Filter="Fullname like '*" & **request.QueryString("term")** & "*'"

    do while not rsElementTem.EOF
        if strArr<>"" then strArr=strArr & ","
        strArr=strArr & "{"&_
                        """value"":""" & rsElementTem("Fullname") & """, ""id"":" & rsElementTem("PersonID") & "}" 

        rsElementTem.MoveNext
    loop
end if


Response.Write "[" & strArr & "]"
```

%>

Comment: And where is the code that filters the data server-side? Do you assume that server automagically knows that as long as `p` received from the client - it needs to filter out only the items with `p` in it?

Comment: from server-site, it returns an array by "response.write" in script.asp. I mean with the same array for two cases, why it works differently?

Comment: because for server-side filtering - it's the server obligation to filter. And plugin accepts the data as-is

Comment: ah... IC, **many thanks Zerkms** , that meam I need ask filter from server-side. I am a newbie of Jquery, could you please give me a link to study how to request filter from sever-side?

Comment: how to request *what*? Your `script.asp` returns the whole array. You need to write a code that accepts user input (from the POST), filters the array and returns the filtered array back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do something similar to what you are after:

**Script.asp:**

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Dim value(6)
Dim id(6)

value(0) = "dog"
id(0) = 1
value(1) = "cat"
id(1) = 20
value(2) = "pig"
id(2) = 31
value(3) = "monkey"
id(3) = 25
value(4) = "camel"
id(4) = 16
value(5) = "carrot"
id(5) = 28
value(6) = "donkey"
id(6) = 9

Dim jsonString
jsonString = "["

For i = 0 to Ubound(value)
    If(left(value(i), Len(Request.Querystring("term"))) = Request.Querystring("term")) Then
    jsonString = jsonString & " { ""value"": """ & value(i) & """, ""id"": " & id(i) & " },"
    End If
Next

jsonString = Left(jsonString, Len(jsonString)-1) & " ]"
Response.Write jsonString
%>
```

This compares the `term` parameter in the querystring with the beginning characters of each element of the array.

For each match, it will add the value to a string in the serialized format.

Finally it will remove the trailing comma with the `Len` function, close the square brackets and output the contents of the string!

Comment: Thanks elliottjmills... I understand how the autocomplete work :)

Comment: :) - I am studying how to make this question be anwsered :D - Can you help me?

Comment: Just click on the outline of the tick on the left of where the answer is :) (http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should bring sorted list from serverside